# withContext inside async

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I already have 2 long running task, each of them wrapped inside withContext. But now I want to run them parallel and wait for the result of them.
So I wonder if I use them like below(wrapped them with async):

```
    val result1 = async { 
      withContext(Dispatcher.IO) { 
        someLongRunningBackgroundWork1...
        ....
      } 
    }

    val 2 = withContext(Dispatcher.IO) { 
        someLongRunningBackgroundWork2...
        ....
      } 
    }
```

This works fine. But I wanted to understand if there is any trade offs behind the scene?

Comment: Tradeoff versus doing what? Note, if everything inside the `async` call uses the same dispatcher, you don't need `withContext` because you can set the context parameter right in the `async` call.

Comment: My functions are already wrapped inside withContext, I don’t want to refactor them. But now if I wrap them inside async would async and withContext will use different thread behind the scenes? What happens to async if I get an exception inside withContext?

Answer (score 2):

`async(Dispatchers.IO) { /*...*/ }` is identical logic as `async { withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { /*...*/} }`. In either case, uncaught exceptions will cause `async` to fail. If you use a bare `async` call like that inside a coroutine, it is a child coroutine and the exception will be propagated to the parent. If `async` is called on a specific CoroutineScope, it is not a child coroutine and will not propagate its exception unless `await()` or `join()` is called on it. Typically, when you want to run some parallel tasks in a coroutine and then continue, you wrap them together in a `coroutineScope` call.

You could do something like this in your coroutine to break down the parallel work. Any uncaught exception thrown inside `coroutineScope` is rethrown outside it, and will cancel any still-running children coroutines inside `coroutineScope`.

```
val (result1, result2) = coroutineScope {
    val result1 = async(Dispatcher.IO) { 
        //someLongRunningBackgroundWork1...
        //....
    }

    val result2 = withContext(Dispatcher.IO) { 
        //someLongRunningBackgroundWork2...
        //....
    } 
    result1.await() to result2
}
```

The advantage over what you have now is that if either of the code blocks fails, the other parallel tasks will automatically be cancelled.

Comment: You said " it is not a child coroutine and will not propagate its exception unless await() or join() is called on it". Do you think that top async/await propagate exception via Job hierarchy? But CEH has no effect in that case.

Comment: @mobiledevAlex Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by CEH? async and await propagate exceptions according to their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As you say in the comment, your functions use `withContext(IO)` and you don't want to change that. Wrapping them in `async` will first start the coroutine in the current dispatcher (if you're on Android, that would be `Main`) and then immediately switch to `IO`. While it won't cost you a lot, it's still unnecessary. If you instead wrap the functions in `async(IO)`, the coroutine will start directly on the correct dispatcher and the inner `withContext(IO) { }` will be basically a no-op.

As Tenfour04 brings up, launching off background work and awaiting on its result should be encompassed by a single unit of work, which should immediately fail as soon as any part of it fails. You don't show where you call `await()` on your launched coroutine, but as a rule both the `async` and `await` statements should occur within the same `coroutineScope` block. When that block is over, you have the guarantee that no ongoing work is left dangling in the background, and you also save time and resources by cancelling it if any other concurrent subtask (or the main task) fails.